# Reading HTTP POST key/values in AWS Lambda Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, aws-lambda, http-headers

When calling a Python Lambda function via HTTP GET, I can read query string parameters using the dictionary **event['queryStringParameters']**.  For example, /test.py?name1=value2&name2=value2, the variable **event['queryStringParameters']** contains this:

```
{'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2'}
```

My understanding is I should be able to do the same with a POST, but I am not having any luck.  Or perhaps event['name1'] should work, but that does not either.

How do I read the pairs when the method is HTTP POST?   Note I'm looking to traverse a list or dictionary of ***all*** keys/values, not just specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format), you should get the POST payload in `event['body']`.

Comment: Yep; a bit more to it though because it looks to in the format of a continuous base64 encoded string

Answer (score 0):

So, here's my solution to create a dictionary called "post_params"

```
import json
import base64
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    body_decoded = base64.b64decode(event['body']).decode("utf-8")
    post_pairs = body_decoded.split("&")
    post_params = dict(p.split('=') for p in post_pairs)
    
    return { 'statusCode': 200, 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'text/json'}, 'body': json.dumps(post_params) }
```